# how to include $scope variables into custom filter function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, wordpress

I have a custom filter, for the input date fields i have a $scope filter to display the string in the format 17/07/2017. can anyone help me how to use the $scope filter in my custom filter function.

my controller function

```
app.controller('OutletController', function ($scope, itemsFactory, $filter) {
        itemsFactory.getItems().success(function (data) {
            $scope.outlets = data;
        })
        $scope.fromDate = $filter('date')($scope.from_date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        $scope.toDate = $filter('date')($scope.to_date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        $scope.format = function (from_date) {
            $scope.fromDate = $filter('date')(from_date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
            //console.log($scope.fromDate);
        }
        $scope.format = function (to_date) {
            $scope.toDate = $filter('date')(to_date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
            // console.log($scope.toDate);
        }
        $scope.parseInt = function (data) {
            if (data == null) return "";
            return parseInt(data);
        };});
```

my html

```
<input type="date" ng-model="from_date" ng-change="format(from_date)">
    <input type="date" ng-model="to_date" ng-change="format(to_date)">
```

ng repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in outlets |  dateRange: {from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date, select: selected.field, select2: selectedone.field} ">
            <td>{{ parseInt(item.offerID) }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.merchant }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.startDate }}</td>
```

my custom Filter

```
app.filter('dateRange', function ($filter) {
        return function (input, params, fromDate, toDate) {
            var from_date = fromDate;
            var to_date = toDate;
            if (isNaN(params.fromDate)) {
                filtered = input;
            }
            else {
                var filtered = [];
                angular.forEach(input, function (item) {
                    if (params.select2 === "strtdate" && params.select === "gt") {
                        console.log(fromDate);
                        if (item.startDate > params.from_date) {
                       filtered.push(item);

                                       }}
                    else {
                   if (item.startDate == params.fromDate) {
       output.push(item);
      }}
                });
            }
            return filtered;
        };
    });
```

whenever put the input date in he from_date field it should filter the dates  > than the input date from the data table.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this below code, also check with this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5uUhzqWW7GtD0uvSjB3f?p=preview) link for your example scenario.

**Template:**

```
    <input type="date" ng-model="Range.From">
    <input type="date" ng-model="Range.To">
    <table border="1">
      <tr ng-repeat="item in outlets | dateRange: Range">
        <td>{{ item.offerID }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.merchant }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.startDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.filter('dateRange', function ($filter) {
  return function (input, params) {
    if(params.From || params.To){
      var filtered = [];
      angular.forEach(input, function (item) {
        var strDate = new Date(item.startDate);
        if(item.startDate >=params.From && item.startDate <= params.To){
          filtered.push(item);
        }else if(item.startDate >= params.From && (params.To===null || params.To===undefined)){
          filtered.push(item);
        }else if(item.startDate <= params.To && (params.From===null || params.From===undefined)){
          filtered.push(item);
        }
      });
      return filtered;
    } else return input;
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Immanuel Kirubaharan. in this function >, < , < > are working my problem is == and != are not working. can you please give me a solution for this.